# NodeJS AWS RDS Connection Database Not Found Error

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services

I am brand new to MySQL and AWS in general so excuse me if this is a silly question but here goes:
I am trying to create a connection between my nodejs application and my MYSQL database hosted on AWS. I have this so far

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "AWS RDS Endpoint",
  user: "username",
  password: "password",
  database: "DB Instance Name on AWS Console"
});

connection.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.error('Database connection failed: ' + err.stack);
    return;
  }

  console.log('Connected to database.');
});

connection.end();
```

When I try running the code I get back "Unknown database 'DB Instance Name on AWS Console'" with the database name being, obviously the db instance name that appears on the AWS console. The password and username I know are correct but I'm not sure about the host or database parameters. Can anyone give me some insight into, if I am doing this correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Last attribute database, should be `DB name` attribute from `configuration` tab, which is default database we choose when creating RDS

OR you can remove `database` attribute completely if you are using an admin credentials.

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "my-mysql-instance.acdefghij.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com",
  user: "username",
  password: "password"
});
```